# For an ergodic Markov chain transition matrix $P = I+P'$ is the $k$th coefficient of $\chi(P')$ $e_k(\text{non-diagonal entiries of }P')$?

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

After playing around in Sympy I found that if I express the transition matrix of a Markov process as the identity plus a secondary matrix, $P'$, then I get an interesting result: the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $P'$ are elementary symmetric polynomials of it's non-diagonal entries.

$$
P = \\
\begin{bmatrix}
1-(P_{12}+P_{13} +\dots) & P_{12} & P_{13} & \dots & P_{1n}\\
P_{21} & 1-(P_{21}+P_{23} +\dots) & P_{23} & \dots & P_{2n}\\
P_{31} & P_{32} & 1-(P_{31}+P_{32} +\dots) & \dots & P_{3n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \\
P_{n1} & P_{n2} & P_{n3} & & 1-(P_{n1}+P_{n2} +\dots)
\end{bmatrix}
 = I-P' \\
\chi(P') = \lambda^{n}+\lambda^{n-1} e_{1}(P_{12},P_{13},\dots)+\lambda^{n-2} e_{2}(P_{12},P_{13},\dots)+\dots+\lambda e_{n-1}(P_{12},P_{13},\dots)
$$

This empirical result looks like it hasn't been discovered, or is at least obscure. I'm having trouble finding confirmation for it. I've been trying to find out how one would go about proving it. The only helpful thing I've found on the internet is that the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are the sums of the principal minors. I've been able to use this fact to show that it's true for the first and second coefficients, but proving it for all of them is turning out to be a pain.

Any help is much appreciated.

Example for three states:
$$
\chi(P') = \lambda^{3}+\lambda^{2}(P_{12}+P_{13}+P_{21}+P_{23}+P_{31}+P_{32})\\
+\lambda(P_{12}P_{13}+P_{12}P_{21}+P_{12}P_{23}+P_{12}P_{31}+P_{12}P_{32}\\
+P_{13}P_{21}+P_{13}P_{23}+P_{13}P_{31}+P_{13}P_{32}\\
+P_{21}P_{23}+P_{21}P_{31}+P_{21}P_{32}\\
+P_{23}P_{31}+P_{23}P_{32}\\
+P_{31}P_{32})
$$

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by "elementary symmetric functions of it's non-diagonal entries?" This is not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry, elementary symmetric polynomials. $e_2(x,y,z) = xy+yz+zx$ for example.

Comment: Just to clarify, you seem to be suggesting the following identity. Consider a polynomial ring in $n^2 - n$ variables $P_{i,j}$ indexed by $\mathcal{I} := \{(i, j) : 1 \leq i, j \leq n, i \neq j\}$. Set $P_{i,i} := 1 - \sum_{j \neq i} P_{i,j}$. Let $Q := (P_{i,j})$ be the corresponding $n \times n$ matrix. Claim: $\det((1+\lambda) I - Q) = \sum_{d=1}^n e_{n-d}(P_{ij}) \lambda^d$ where $e_k(P_{ij}) := \sum_{\mathcal{J} \subset \mathcal{I}, |\mathcal{J}|=k} \prod_{(i, j) \in \mathcal{J}} P_{i,j}$. Correct?

Comment: In your example, how are you getting $P_{12}P_{13}$ in your expression? I get only 9 terms on $\lambda^1$ instead of all $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ that you've written down. The issue is there's no way we'll multiply $P_{i, j}$ and $P_{i, j'}$. In my product over $\mathcal{J}$, we at least need to require the $i$-coordinates of the elements of $\mathcal{J}$ are distinct. Additionally, in your example I get that we need to omit $P_{12}P_{21}, P_{13}P_{31}, P_{23}P_{32}$. In any case, there's a remarkable amount of cancellation. It's likely a sign-reversing involution will prove the correct statement.

Comment: Oh my gosh, you're right. You should answer the question so I can give you credit for it.

Comment: It's grown too late, but I think the right idea is to apply Laplace expansion, expand everything into monomials, and analyze the ways in which a particular monomial can arise. I'm not immediately seeing exactly what the condition should be on the monomials that survive. It's easy to see you can always cancel $P_{ij}P_{ji}$, and I believe larger cycles as well.